# Access Bing translate service with PHP and SOAP

Tags: php, api, search, bing

Does anyone know how to access Bing Translate service (search api 2.0) with PHP and SOAP? I've been trying different ways but none was yet successful. Here's my code:

```
$soap=new SoapClient("http://api.search.live.net/search.wsdl");//"http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/03/Search"
        $params["AppId"]="";
        $params["Query"]=$term;
        $params["SourceLanguage"]=$lang_from;
        $params["TargetLanguage"]=$lang_to;
        $params["Sources"]="Translation";
        //$params["Translation"]=array(
          //"Translation"=>array(
            //"SourceLanguage"=>$lang_from,
            //"TargetLanguage"=>$lang_to
          //)
        //);
        //$params["Sources"]=$sources;
        //$params["definitions"]="";
        //$res=$soap->Search(array("parameters"=>$params));
        die(print_r($soap->Search(array("parameters"=>$params))));
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try this simple method?

http://www.som3on3.com/programming/php/php-bing-translate-api/